# Assigning a value to a **@type : webpage** URL in schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm a little bit confused about assigning a value to a **@type : webpage** url in schema.org, using JSON-LD.
Surfing on internet I found two types of URL values.
The first type is with the / at the end of the URL : "url": "https://example.org/subpage/"
The second one is without the / at the end of the URL : "url": "https://example.org/subpage"
I wonder which of the two is correct or if it makes any difference.
For my website, anyway, if I try to open subpages with the final / I got an Internal Server Error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Data type: URL
https://schema.org/URL

URL's with and without slashes are treated as `two different` URL's.
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27714/difference-between-at-end-of-url-and-without

If you put **broken** URL (relative -or- absolute) - You point to another page + `404 Not Found page`. Of course, this is "bad practice" (So in your case you should use `"url": "https://example.org/subpage"`).

Sometimes on the **server**, you could do `301` Redirect to one of them from the other (But this is not related to **schema.org**).

**SUM:** URL == Text that's represent the URL of the item (Schema.org does not handle your [SEO best practices for URLs](https://moz.com/learn/seo/url), broken links, 301, and so on). If your page URL is `https://example.org/subpage/` use `"url": "https://example.org/subpage/"`.